Cannot find symbol: class SpringExtension
I'm trying to utilise the class SpringExtension for test classes using JUnit5 with the following syntax:
@SpringBootTest @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

However, I am met with the following error upon runtime:

java: cannot find symbol   symbol: class SpringExtension

My POM file looks like this:
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>gown-qub-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.224</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-postgres-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.9</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.6.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql:postgres</url>
                    <user>user</user>
                    <password>password</password>
                </jdbc>

                <generator>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes></excludes>
                        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>org.jooq.codegen.maven.example</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

Are there any imports I am missing?
I expected to be able to import the class as a dependency but that does not seem possible.


Your dependencies are quite messy

unneeded dependencies
mixing modules from different Spring Boot versions
including incompatible versions of Spring dependencies.


You should use the spring-boot-starter-test dependency to include the needed test dependencies.

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>gown-qub-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>22</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.224</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-postgres-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

Final tip: remove the @ExtendWith as you don't need it, that is already automatically part of the @SpringBootTest annotation.
